# How to correctly pack an unsigned long from 3 unsigned chars?

Tags: arduino-uno, memory-usage, progmem

I would like to use 652 unsigned long values on an Arduino Uno, but it doesn't look like there's enough memory. I thought about the splitting unsigned long values to 3 unsigned chars to store in PROGMEM which I can letter recall and join as unsigned long as needed.

I'm not super experienced with byte manipulations and I got myself stuck when trying to merge the data. When I try with one variable at a time, I get the expected output. The part I'm confused about is why do I get different values when using a variable as an array index for each value ? How can I fix this ?

Here's my test code so far:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include "flashData.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  unsigned long fromPROGMEM = (onsets1[0] << 16) | (onsets2[0] << 8) | onsets3[0]; 
  Serial.println(fromPROGMEM);

  unsigned long fromValues = (0x00 << 16) | (0x01 << 8) | 0xF3;
  Serial.println(fromValues);

  byte b1 = 0x00;
  byte b2 = 0x01;
  byte b3 = 0xF3;

  unsigned long fromBytes = (b1 << 16) | (b2 << 8) | b3;

  Serial.println(fromBytes);
  delay(2000);

  unsigned char c1,c2,c3;
  unsigned long value;

  Serial.println("data using same index:");
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
    c1 = onsets1[3];
    c2 = onsets2[3];
    c3 = onsets3[3];
    value = (c1 << 16) | (c2 << 8) | c3; 
    Serial.print("index: ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("\tvalue:");
    Serial.println (value);
    delay(10);
  }

  Serial.println("data using counter:");
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
    c1 = onsets1[i];
    c2 = onsets2[i];
    c3 = onsets3[i];
    value = (c1 << 16) | (c2 << 8) | c3; 
    Serial.print("index: ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("\tvalue:");
    Serial.println (value);
    delay(10);
  }
}

void loop() {

}
```

and flashData.h:

```
#ifndef _flashData_h_
#define _flashData_h_

static PROGMEM const unsigned char onsets1[652] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03};
static PROGMEM const unsigned char onsets2[652] = {0x01,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0A,0x0D,0x0E,0x0F,0x10,0x11,0x12,0x14,0x15,0x16,0x17,0x18,0x19,0x1A,0x1B,0x1D,0x1E,0x1F,0x20,0x21,0x22,0x23,0x25,0x26,0x28,0x29,0x2A,0x2B,0x2C,0x2E,0x2F,0x30,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x38,0x39,0x3A,0x3B,0x3C,0x3F,0x40,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44,0x45,0x46,0x48,0x49,0x4A,0x4C,0x4D,0x4E,0x51,0x52,0x53,0x54,0x55,0x56,0x57,0x59,0x5A,0x5B,0x5C,0x5E,0x5F,0x61,0x63,0x64,0x65,0x67,0x6A,0x6B,0x6C,0x6D,0x6E,0x70,0x71,0x73,0x75,0x76,0x77,0x79,0x7C,0x7E,0x7F,0x80,0x82,0x84,0x85,0x86,0x87,0x88,0x89,0x8A,0x8C,0x8D,0x8E,0x8F,0x90,0x91,0x92,0x95,0x96,0x97,0x98,0x99,0x9A,0x9B,0x9C,0x9E,0x9F,0xA0,0xA1,0xA2,0xA3,0xA4,0xA7,0xA8,0xA9,0xAA,0xAB,0xAC,0xAD,0xAF,0xB0,0xB1,0xB2,0xB3,0xB4,0xB5,0xB6,0xB9,0xBA,0xBB,0xBC,0xBD,0xBE,0xC0,0xC2,0xC4,0xC6,0xC9,0xCB,0xCD,0xCF,0xD2,0xD4,0xD6,0xD8,0xDA,0xDB,0xDD,0xDF,0xE0,0xE2,0xE4,0xE6,0xE7,0xE8,0xE9,0xEB,0xEC,0xED,0xEE,0xEF,0xF0,0xF1,0xF2,0xF4,0xF6,0xF7,0xF8,0xF9,0xFA,0xFD,0xFE,0xFF,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x0A,0x0D,0x0F,0x10,0x11,0x12,0x13,0x14,0x16,0x18,0x19,0x1A,0x1C,0x1D,0x1F,0x21,0x22,0x23,0x25,0x28,0x2A,0x2B,0x2C,0x2E,0x30,0x31,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x38,0x3C,0x3D,0x3E,0x41,0x42,0x44,0x45,0x46,0x47,0x48,0x4A,0x4B,0x4C,0x4D,0x4E,0x4F,0x50,0x53,0x54,0x56,0x57,0x58,0x59,0x5B,0x5C,0x5D,0x5E,0x5F,0x60,0x61,0x63,0x65,0x66,0x67,0x69,0x6A,0x6D,0x6E,0x6F,0x70,0x71,0x72,0x73,0x75,0x77,0x78,0x79,0x7A,0x7B,0x7D,0x7E,0x7F,0x80,0x82,0x84,0x87,0x89,0x8B,0x8E,0x90,0x92,0x94,0x97,0x99,0x9B,0x9D,0xA0,0xA2,0xA4,0xA5,0xA6,0xA8,0xA9,0xAA,0xAB,0xAC,0xAD,0xAE,0xAF,0xB1,0xB2,0xB3,0xB4,0xB5,0xB6,0xB9,0xBA,0xBB,0xBD,0xBF,0xC0,0xC2,0xC4,0xC6,0xC7,0xC8,0xCB,0xCC,0xCD,0xCE,0xCF,0xD1,0xD4,0xD5,0xD6,0xD7,0xD8,0xD9,0xDA,0xDC,0xDD,0xDE,0xDF,0xE0,0xE1,0xE2,0xE4,0xE6,0xE8,0xEA,0xEB,0xED,0xEF,0xF1,0xF2,0xF3,0xF5,0xF6,0xF8,0xF9,0xFA,0xFB,0xFC,0xFF,0x01,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0A,0x0B,0x0C,0x0D,0x0F,0x10,0x11,0x12,0x13,0x15,0x16,0x18,0x19,0x1A,0x1B,0x1C,0x1D,0x1E,0x20,0x21,0x23,0x24,0x25,0x27,0x29,0x2A,0x2B,0x2C,0x2D,0x2E,0x30,0x32,0x33,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x3A,0x3B,0x3C,0x3E,0x40,0x43,0x44,0x45,0x47,0x48,0x49,0x4A,0x4C,0x4D,0x4E,0x50,0x55,0x56,0x57,0x59,0x5A,0x5B,0x5E,0x5F,0x60,0x61,0x62,0x63,0x65,0x66,0x67,0x68,0x69,0x6B,0x6C,0x6F,0x70,0x71,0x72,0x73,0x74,0x76,0x77,0x79,0x7A,0x7B,0x7D,0x7F,0x80,0x81,0x82,0x83,0x84,0x85,0x86,0x88,0x89,0x8A,0x8B,0x8C,0x8D,0x90,0x91,0x92,0x93,0x94,0x95,0x96,0x97,0x99,0x9B,0x9D,0x9F,0xA2,0xA4,0xA6,0xA8,0xAB,0xAD,0xAF,0xB1,0xB4,0xB6,0xB7,0xB8,0xBB,0xBD,0xBE,0xBF,0xC0,0xC1,0xC2,0xC4,0xC5,0xC6,0xC7,0xC8,0xC9,0xCA,0xCC,0xCD,0xCE,0xCF,0xD1,0xD3,0xD6,0xD8,0xDA,0xDC,0xDE,0xDF,0xE0,0xE1,0xE3,0xE4,0xE5,0xE7,0xE8,0xE9,0xEA,0xEC,0xEF,0xF0,0xF1,0xF2,0xF3,0xF4,0xF5,0xF7,0xF8,0xF9,0xFA,0xFB,0xFC,0xFE,0x01,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x07,0x09,0x0A,0x0B,0x0C,0x0E,0x10,0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,0x17,0x18,0x1A,0x1C,0x1E,0x1F,0x20,0x21,0x23,0x24,0x25,0x26,0x27,0x28,0x29,0x2B,0x2C,0x2D,0x2E,0x2F,0x30,0x31,0x32,0x34,0x35,0x37,0x39,0x3C,0x3E,0x40,0x42,0x43,0x45,0x47,0x49,0x4A,0x4B,0x4C,0x4E,0x50,0x52,0x53,0x54,0x56,0x57,0x58,0x59,0x5B,0x5C,0x5D,0x5F,0x60,0x61,0x62,0x64,0x66,0x68,0x69,0x6B,0x6C,0x6D,0x6E,0x70,0x71,0x72,0x74,0x75,0x76,0x78,0x79,0x7B,0x7C,0x7D,0x7F,0x80,0x81,0x82,0x83,0x84,0x85,0x86,0x87,0x88,0x8A,0x8B,0x8C,0x8D,0x8F,0x90,0x91,0x93,0x94,0x95,0x96,0x97,0x98,0x9B,0x9D,0x9F,0xA1};
static PROGMEM const unsigned char onsets3[652] = {0xF3,0x31,0x59,0x76,0x98,0xBA,0xDD,0xFF,0x43,0x66,0x88,0xAA,0xC7,0xEF,0x0B,0x2D,0x50,0x72,0x8E,0xB1,0xD3,0xF5,0x17,0x3A,0x5C,0x7E,0xA0,0xC8,0xE5,0x0D,0x29,0x6E,0x90,0xAC,0xD5,0xF7,0x13,0x35,0x58,0x7A,0x9C,0xB9,0xE1,0xFD,0x42,0x6A,0x86,0xA8,0xC5,0x0F,0x31,0x54,0x7C,0x92,0xB5,0xCB,0xF9,0x1B,0x43,0x60,0xA4,0xC1,0xE3,0x28,0x4A,0x72,0x8E,0xB1,0xD3,0xF5,0x17,0x34,0x5C,0x78,0xBD,0xDF,0x01,0x46,0x62,0x84,0xCF,0x0D,0x30,0x52,0x7A,0x91,0xD5,0xF7,0x1A,0x5E,0x86,0xA3,0xE7,0x26,0x5F,0x92,0xAF,0xF3,0x1B,0x32,0x5A,0x7C,0x9F,0xBB,0xE3,0x00,0x28,0x4A,0x66,0x89,0xAB,0xC7,0x0C,0x34,0x4A,0x72,0x95,0xB7,0xD9,0xFB,0x1E,0x3A,0x62,0x7F,0x9B,0xC3,0xE0,0x2A,0x52,0x69,0x91,0xB3,0xD5,0xF7,0x1F,0x36,0x58,0x80,0x9D,0xB9,0xE1,0xF8,0x42,0x65,0x81,0xA9,0xCB,0xE8,0x10,0x54,0x93,0xD2,0x16,0x60,0x9F,0xE4,0x28,0x6D,0xAB,0xF0,0x12,0x34,0x79,0xB2,0xDA,0x02,0x46,0x85,0xAD,0xCF,0xF2,0x0E,0x30,0x4D,0x75,0x97,0xB9,0xD0,0xFE,0x1A,0x65,0x87,0xA3,0xC5,0xE2,0x2C,0x4E,0x6B,0x8D,0xAF,0xD7,0xEE,0x38,0x5B,0x77,0xC1,0x00,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xAB,0xCE,0xF0,0x01,0x57,0x7F,0x95,0xDA,0xFC,0x1E,0x5D,0x7F,0x9C,0xE0,0x25,0x6F,0x91,0xAE,0xF2,0x14,0x3C,0x7B,0x98,0xBA,0x04,0x82,0xAF,0xCC,0x16,0x33,0x77,0x94,0xBC,0xD2,0xFA,0x1D,0x3F,0x61,0x7D,0xA6,0xC8,0xE4,0x29,0x51,0x8F,0xAC,0xCE,0xF0,0x13,0x35,0x57,0x79,0x9C,0xBE,0xE0,0x02,0x47,0x69,0x8B,0xCA,0xF2,0x31,0x53,0x75,0x98,0xBA,0xD6,0xF9,0x15,0x5F,0x82,0xA4,0xC6,0xE8,0x05,0x33,0x60,0x7D,0xBC,0xFA,0x3F,0x83,0xC2,0x0C,0x51,0x95,0xD4,0x18,0x5D,0xA1,0xE0,0x25,0x69,0xA8,0xD0,0xE7,0x0F,0x31,0x53,0x75,0x98,0xB4,0xDC,0xF9,0x1B,0x3D,0x5F,0x7C,0xA4,0xC0,0x05,0x21,0x49,0x88,0xD2,0xF4,0x11,0x55,0x94,0xBC,0xDE,0x1D,0x4B,0x62,0x8F,0xAC,0xF0,0x2F,0x57,0x74,0x96,0xB2,0xD5,0xF7,0x1F,0x3B,0x63,0x86,0xAE,0xC4,0xEC,0x09,0x47,0x8C,0xD0,0xF3,0x15,0x54,0x98,0xC0,0xE2,0x05,0x21,0x66,0x88,0xA4,0xD2,0xEF,0x39,0x72,0xBC,0xD9,0xFB,0x23,0x3F,0x62,0x84,0xA0,0xC3,0xF0,0x07,0x2F,0x4C,0x74,0x90,0xCF,0xF7,0x13,0x3B,0x58,0x74,0x9C,0xB9,0xDB,0x03,0x1F,0x6A,0x86,0xA3,0xED,0x0F,0x31,0x4E,0x76,0x92,0xB5,0xF9,0x27,0x38,0x7C,0xA4,0xC1,0x05,0x28,0x4A,0x8E,0xCD,0x11,0x3A,0x50,0x9B,0xBD,0xDF,0x93,0x24,0x40,0x68,0xA7,0x2A,0x58,0x74,0xB9,0xDB,0xF7,0x3C,0x5E,0x80,0xA3,0xC5,0xE7,0x09,0x2C,0x48,0x70,0x8D,0xD1,0xF9,0x38,0x54,0x77,0x9F,0xBB,0xDD,0x00,0x22,0x60,0x83,0x9F,0xE9,0x11,0x2E,0x50,0x72,0x95,0xB7,0xDF,0xFB,0x18,0x40,0x5C,0x7F,0xA1,0xB8,0x08,0x2A,0x46,0x6E,0x8B,0xAD,0xD5,0xFD,0x14,0x58,0x97,0xDC,0x20,0x59,0xA9,0xEE,0x32,0x71,0xB5,0xF4,0x38,0x77,0x99,0xC1,0x06,0x4A,0x6D,0x8F,0xAB,0xCE,0xF0,0x0C,0x34,0x57,0x79,0x95,0xBD,0xDA,0x02,0x1E,0x46,0x5D,0xA7,0xE6,0x25,0x6F,0xAE,0xF2,0x14,0x37,0x5F,0x7B,0xC0,0xE8,0xFE,0x21,0x43,0x6B,0x8D,0xC6,0x10,0x33,0x55,0x77,0x99,0xBC,0xD8,0x00,0x1D,0x45,0x5B,0x83,0xA0,0xE4,0x29,0x67,0x8F,0xAC,0xF0,0x18,0x35,0x63,0x79,0xB8,0xFD,0xC1,0x4D,0x6F,0x86,0xCA,0xF2,0x09,0x4D,0x92,0xBA,0xD6,0xF9,0x15,0x37,0x59,0x82,0xA4,0xBA,0xE8,0x05,0x27,0x49,0x6B,0x8E,0xAA,0xCC,0xEF,0x17,0x33,0x78,0xB6,0x01,0x3F,0x7E,0xC3,0xEB,0x07,0x4C,0x90,0xB2,0xD5,0xFD,0x19,0x5E,0xA2,0xBE,0xE1,0x03,0x25,0x47,0x64,0xAE,0xD6,0xED,0x15,0x31,0x59,0x76,0xB5,0xF9,0x1B,0x3E,0x7C,0xA4,0xC7,0xE9,0x0B,0x33,0x50,0x8E,0xB6,0xD9,0x01,0x11,0x56,0x7E,0x95,0xDF,0x9F,0x13,0x29,0x46,0x68,0x8A,0xAC,0xC9,0xEB,0x0D,0x2A,0x52,0x6E,0xAD,0xCF,0xF7,0x25,0x30,0x64,0x7B,0xA3,0xBF,0x09,0x42,0x8D,0xCB};


#endif
```

And here's what I see from Serial:

```
499
499
499
data using same index:
index: 0    value:1654
index: 1    value:1654
index: 2    value:1654
index: 3    value:1654
index: 4    value:1654
index: 5    value:1654
index: 6    value:1654
index: 7    value:1654
index: 8    value:1654
index: 9    value:1654
data using counter:
index: 0    value:4294945024
index: 1    value:4294962688
index: 2    value:12806
index: 3    value:28928
index: 4    value:4294948096
index: 5    value:4294964224
index: 6    value:14337
index: 7    value:30464
index: 8    value:4294940928
index: 9    value:4294951174
```

I see what I expect for first 3 values and also for data using same index, but no when using a variable as an index for the PROGMEM arrays.

What is going on and how can I fix this ?

**Update**
Mikael's answer is the solution, but I will post a working snippet here for reference:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include "flashData.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(2000);

  unsigned char c1,c2,c3;
  unsigned long value;

  Serial.println("data using counter:");
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 652; i++){
    c1 = (unsigned char) pgm_read_byte(&onsets1[i]);
    c2 = (unsigned char) pgm_read_byte(&onsets2[i]);
    c3 = (unsigned char) pgm_read_byte(&onsets3[i]);
    value = (((unsigned long) c1) << 16) | ((unsigned long)c2 << 8) | (unsigned long)c3; 
    Serial.print("index: ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("\tvalue:");
    Serial.println (value);
    delay(10);
  }

}

void loop() {

}
```

The key is not only explicitly casting the data read, but also correctly reading the the PROGMEM data.

Comment: An `unsigned long` needs 4 `unsigned char`s.

Comment: Can you please expand ? In my case the data won't need a 4th unsigned char. I've tried ```(0 << 24) | (c1 << 16) | (c2 << 8) | c3``` but the result looks the same.

Comment: You don't need to store `onsets1`. The values it holds are simple to generate at runtime. I'd also look at encoding the values in `onsets2` differently, probably as a length and an increment. So the first pair would be 1 and 3, because there's one value (1), followed by an increment of 3 to produce 4. The next pair would be 7 and 3, because there are 7 sequential values (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A) and the next value is 3 more than the end of that sequence. Etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try (explict unsigned long values):

```
unsigned long fromValues = (0x00UL << 16) | (0x01 << 8) | 0xF3;
Serial.println(fromValues);
```

or:

```
value = (((unsigned long) c1) << 16) | (c2 << 8) | c3;
```

The issue is that the expression is implicit int and not long (as you are assuming). You need to tell the compiler about this.

An extra bonus comment: There is actually a 24 bit integer definition in AVR GCC according to the [wiki, see Extensions, Types](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc).

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you(+1) Mikael, explicitly casting to unsigned long makes sense. However I think this might not be the main issue. This part (```unsigned long fromValues = (0x00UL << 16) | (0x01 << 8) | 0xF3;
Serial.println(fromValues);```) works as expected, this part ```value = (((unsigned long) c1) << 16) | (c2 << 8) | c3; ``` only works when I access the PROGMEM arrays using a constant value (e.g. ```c1 = onsets1[3];``` works, ```c1 = onsets1[i];``` produces strange results). I haven't used PROGMEM before, so maybe I'm retrieving/addressing data the wrong way ?

Comment: You need to add explicit read of PROGMEM: `c1 = (unsigned char) pgm_read_byte(&onsets1[i])`. Please see [avr/pgmspace.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html). I have also put together a more advanced example [Sketchbook/ProgramMemory](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Sketchbook/tree/master/ProgramMemory).

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by typecasting firmly and using multiplications:

```
  Serial.println("data using counter:");
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
    c1 = onsets1[i];
    c2 = onsets2[i];
    c3 = onsets3[i];
    value = (uint8_t)c3 + (uint16_t)((uint8_t)c2*256)+(uint32_t)(c1*65536);
    Serial.print("index: ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(c1, HEX);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(c2, HEX);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(c3, HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print("\tvalue:");
    Serial.println (value, HEX);
  }
```

The result:

> ```
> data using counter:
> index: 0    A1, F6, 0   value:A1F600
> index: 1    FC, A7, 0   value:FCA700
> index: 2    B5, 7A, B8  value:B57AB8
> index: 3    EF, DB, 0   value:EFDB00
> index: 4    14, F9, 0   value:14F900
> index: 5    D7, 7F, 0   value:D77F00
> index: 6    F2, 72, 1   value:F27201
> index: 7    6F, DB, 0   value:6FDB00
> index: 8    5E, 5E, 0   value:5E5E00
> index: 9    F0, E7, B8  value:F0E7B8
> ```

Comment: Thank you (+1). The issue is that these aren't stored values in PROGMEM, so my issue might actually be about retrieving values from PROGMEM. If you look in the flashData.h, you'll see the first values should be ```0x00,0x01,0xF3```, not ```0xA1,0xF6,0x00```.